# Equivalent circuits with one or multiple resistors

Tags: voltage, resistors, dc

I am designing a circuit but I am facing a repetitive design that require too many resistors. The problem comes down to answering if the next two circuits are equivalent in terms of voltage drops:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffhpKj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb4FjL.png)</sup>

Note that there are actually **n** resistors: R2,R3,...Rn. All values are known and can be different from each other(R2<>R3<>R4<>...<>Rn) and R1,R2,..Rn have the same values in both scenarios (the values on the drawing are incorrect).
The question is as it folows: Is the voltage drop on R2,R3,...,Rn same in both scenarios?

Comment: you say that the resistors can have different values, then you say that they are all the same ..... why did you say that they could have different values? ... that statement appears to be irrelevant

Comment: They have the same value in BOTH scenarios. Read again. By logic if I made the affirmation R2<>R3<>. etc means I knew what I was writing and that you should have read it again more carefully. Also they CAN have different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly not!

Consider if R2 is 0 ohms, then in the op circuit there is NO VOLTAGE developed across any of R2-Rn because they are all short circuited by the 0 ohm R2. Clearly further in the first circuit the voltage is the SAME across all resistors R2-Rn because they are in parallel.

In the second case you have a number of individual potential dividers, so having a zero ohm resistor for R2 only means the voltage drop across R2 is zero, it says nothing about R3-Rn which may all have different values and form different potential dividers.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Not unless you change \$R1\$, and even then not in practical circuits.

---

In circuit 1, the current for all four lower resistors flows through R1.

In circuit 2, there is no such common current flow. The current through each of the R1's will only be that of a single lower resistor.

In your case, the second circuit will divide the voltage by two in each branch. The first circuit will divide the voltage by five.

---

You can do a simple calculation to work out that this is the case.

**Circuit 1**

The effective resistance of the bottom parallel set of resistors in the first circuit can be found - if you have \$n\$ equal resistors \$R_b\$ in parallel, then the total effective resistance is \$\frac{R_b}{n}\$.

Using the potential divider equation, you can then calculate that the voltage at the mid node will be

$$V_o = V_i \times \frac{R_b/n}{R_b/n + R_t} = V_i \times \frac{R_b}{R_b + nR_t}$$

**Circuit 2**

For the second circuit, you effectively have \$n\$ independent branches. To work out the voltage of the middle node in each circuit the calculation is simply:

$$V_o = V_i \times \frac{Rb}{Rb + Rt}$$

**Summary**

As you can see from the equations, for any value of \$n \ne1\$, the voltage at the mid node of each lower resistor will be different.

There is however a way to make them the same, and that is to change the value of \$R_t\$. By setting \$R_{t\space(circuit\space2)} = n\times R_{t\space(circuit\space1)}\$, then the two equations will be equal.

**However**, this only works for **ideal** resistors. In practice you will never get \$n\$ equal resistors. Each one will be different. As such, the voltage drop across the lower resistor in each branch of circuit 2 will not be equal. In circuit 1 the voltage drops will always be equal.

---

The equations above are assuming that **all the bottom resistors are the same**. It is however quite possible to calculate equations in a similar manner for the cause when the bottom resistors are different - rather than having \$\frac{R_b}{n}\$ you would have whatever the parallel combination of the resistors is. For circuit 2, you would end up with a different value of \$nR_t\$ for each branch.

Even with different values, the two circuits will produce different results, so the conclusion is unchanged.

Comment: This is a very perfect answer with proof but I consider the one I voted as being more intuitive(the short circuit idea never came to me). This answer is equally right and for those who seek proof.

Comment: The OP said that the values are actually **not** the same, so your equations that contain \$n\$ will not work in the general case.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson but actually that doesn't matter too much - the two circuits would still be different, and there would still be some value of \$n\$ that would work, albeit a different \$n\$ for each parallel branch.